# Grails: Trying to display picture but not working

Tags: html, image, grails, groovy

Hey there,
I was trying to display a picture using regular HTML

I have this,

`<img src="../../web-app/images/cargo.png" align="left"/>`

Maybe I'm doing something wrong there backing up directories with the "../../"
But last time I checked that's how it was done

If there is a simpler and better way to do it via Groovy, or maybe CSS, I'd appreciate the help, Thanks

FG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grails way:

```
<img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'cargo.png')}" />
```